# How to create a commit from a diff or patch using GitHub's API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Given a `.patch` file (or any kind of diff, however it's stored), is that possible to apply it to a repository on a given branch **using only GitHub's API**?

I've seen the [`Update file` API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file). But it only supports updating one file at a time, creating as many commits as there are files, so not a good solution.

I've also seen the [`Create commit` endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit), but I don't really understand how I create the content of the commit. I'm wondering if I should not upload the patch [as a blob first](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#create-a-blob) but I'm not sure at all how it works…

#### Why?

The reason for not using git is that I want to avoid cloning the repository, or even having the repository on disk.

I'm building a SaaS application and if there's any way I can avoid storing a 3rd-party's code on a disk, even for just a minute, I'd like that as it's much safer.

The diff will be generated by downloading [the archived version of the repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) and running a tool in the directory. For that step I will have to download the code, but at least I don't download the whole history. The directory will be erased right after the `.patch` file is generated.

If there's any other way I'm also open to that.

Comment: How about simply doing a shallow clone?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe GitHub provides any API that will let you provide patch data and automatically construct a commit. However, if you're really dedicated to this, you could parse the patch file, request the original contents of each changed path from GitHub's API (e.g. using the [`getContents` API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content)), apply the patch in-memory, and [create a new blob](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#create-a-blob) with the updated contents. Once you have updated blobs for all the changed files, you can [create a new tree](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree) that includes all the new blobs in the right locations, then [create a commit](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#create-a-commit) which references the tree.

This is assuming the patch applies cleanly. If you want to handle conflicts correctly, your best bet is probably to use a full local checkout.